# facebook like iframe button, displays when it links to a url, but not the facebook page (safari only) works in FF

Tags: button, iframe, facebook-like

really strange one for me here.....

i have put a facebook like button onto a website (iframe) and it displays fine in firefox, but does not appear in safari, the page i'm linking to is http://www.facebook.com/corporategolfventures

if i link to the main site - http://www.corporategolfventures.co.uk/ the button shows up in safari and works just fine, but i need the like button to link to the facebook business page.

any ideas?

thanks

Neil

PS. I just realised that it only shows in firefox when you're logged into facebook.... still dont know how to fix this though :(